# WhiteRaccon not send files .txt

Tags: objective-c, ftp, send

I would like to send a text file that contains a JSON (.txt file) - send via FTP using the library **White Raccoon**. Unfortunately sends me the following error displaying:

> AppName[2174:822208] -[WRRequestListDirectory stream:handleEvent:]
>   [Line 982] Unknown error!
>
> The file is located in the following
>   folder:/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7D20A84E-29F4-4F1B-A7B2-A1252FD97A97/Documents/aztec_BAG1022413.txt

The code, the one I use:

```
        WRRequestUpload * uploadJSON = [[WRRequestUpload alloc] init];
        uploadJSON.delegate = self;
        uploadJSON.hostname = @"hostname";
        uploadJSON.username = @"username";
        uploadJSON.password = @"password";
        uploadJSON.path = [NSString stringWithFormat: filePath];
        [uploadJSON start];
```

I look forward to help.

Answer (score 0):

Not much to go on but for hostname try using the host address alone for eg: "domain.com" instead of "ftp://domain.com". If that doesn't help can you try passive mode?

Comment: I used the "ftp: //" prefix and does not work still. Thank you for your response.